# How toaccess properties / values from a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reflection, mirror

I want to access my view objects from `UITableViewCell`, but I cannot. I can't cast my cell object because I only have the string `UITableViewCell`. For example "ClientTableViewCell".

How can I access the views and objects in the cell without casting?
I tried to do as follows:

```
let cell = (val as AnyObject).dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClientTableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell
```

I can get a cell like this but I can't reach the contents.Itried mirror reflection like this:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: cell)
```

but child label and value comes some optional

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by *"access my view objects"* ... Are you talking about setting properties / values when you want to display the table? Or are you trying to get properties / values ***from*** a cell that is already displayed?

Comment: Do you not have access to the tableView? Should it just be `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClientTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ClientTableViewCell`

Comment: @rhpekarek I do not want to cast to ClientTableViewCell, I have only "ClientTableViewCell" as a string. So I will get this as a string from the service and I need to make it generic for all UITableViewCell.  Instead of ClientTableViewCell, UserTableViewCell can also be used as a string.

Comment: You seem to be making life hard for yourself. You might as well just have a big switch statement that casts the cell to the right type based on the string value you have. Swift doesn't have strong reflection capabilities and you can't have new cell types that weren't know about at compile time anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, since your cell inherits from `NSObject` you could just use `value(forKey:)` to access the cell's properties without needing to cast the object to a specific cell subclass.   Note that your cell properties would need to be declared as `@Objc`

Comment: @Paulw11 unfortunately  my cell properties is IBOutlet weak

Comment: You can still add the @objc modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let cell: ClientTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ClientTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? ClientTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
```

try this

Comment: I do not want to cast to ClientTableViewCell, I have only "ClientTableViewCell" as a string. So I will get this as a string from the service and I need to make it generic for all UITableViewCell.